# JSONPath query returns same-named keys from nested objects when I only want the parent object

Tags: json, kettle, jsonpath

I'm currently working with Pentaho Kettle for some ETL jobs, and I need to integrate a JSON feed, which means I need to use JSONPath to grab data. For the most part, it's working well, except some of the JSON data is nested objects with the same field name in both parent and child.

**Example JSON:**

```
[
  {
    "Key": "5e59d536-2e3c-487c-bff1-efd0a706532f",
    "Product": {
      "Name": "Some Product",
      "LastUpdated": "2013-08-23T12:10:25.454",
    },
    "Reviewer": {
      "Email": "blah@foo.com",
      "LastUpdated": "2013-08-23T12:10:25.454",
    },
    "LastUpdated": "2013-08-23T12:10:25.407",
  },
  {
    "Key": "f3ae6a4b-1a20-4a9a-9a8e-2de5949c4493",
    "Product": {
      "Name": "Some Product",
      "LastUpdated": "2013-08-23T12:10:51.896",
    },
    "Reviewer": {
      "Email": "blah@foo.com",
      "LastUpdated": "2013-08-23T12:10:51.896",
    },
    "LastUpdated": "2013-08-23T12:10:51.896",
  },
  {
    "Key": "de01c358-6c74-473c-8cd4-a44cf50132df",
    "Product": {
      "Name": "Some Product",
      "LastUpdated": "2013-08-26T10:30:13.617",
    },
    "Reviewer": {
      "Email": "blah@foo.com",
      "LastUpdated": "2013-08-26T10:30:13.617",
    },
    "LastUpdated": "2013-08-26T10:30:13.601",
    },
  },
  {
    "Key": "af04e48a-3ce8-4227-a00a-14483ca75058",
    "Product": {
      "Name": "Some Product",
      "LastUpdated": "2013-08-26T10:31:20.573",
    },
    "Reviewer": {
      "Email": "blah@foo.com",
      "LastUpdated": "2013-08-26T10:31:20.573",
    },
    "LastUpdated": "2013-08-26T10:31:20.573",
  },
  {
    "Key": "d1a787bb-37d2-4ea9-84fd-5a3d454b9127",
    "Product": {
      "Name": "Some Product",
      "LastUpdated": "2013-08-27T11:59:56.777",
    },
    "Reviewer": {
      "Email": "blah@foo.com",
      "LastUpdated": "2013-08-27T11:59:56.777",
    },
    "LastUpdated": "2013-08-27T11:59:56.73",
  },
  {
    "Key": "d8646319-af27-464f-bd50-d61e035800c6",
    "Product": {
      "Name": "Some Product",
      "LastUpdated": "2013-08-27T19:43:06.928",
    },
    "Reviewer": {
      "Email": "blah@foo.com",
      "LastUpdated": "2013-08-27T19:43:06.928",
    },
    "LastUpdated": "2013-08-27T19:43:06.866",
  },
]
```

As you can see, the parent object, and its child objects "Product" and "Reviewer" all have "LastUpdated" fields. I'm trying to get the parent object's "LastUpdated" only, but using:

```
$..LastUpdated
```

returns, in order, the parent LastUpdated, Product LastUpdated, then Reviewer LastUpdated.

**RESULTS:**

```
[
   "2013-08-23T12:10:25.407",
   "2013-08-23T12:10:25.454",
   "2013-08-23T12:10:25.454",
   "2013-08-23T12:10:51.896",
   "2013-08-23T12:10:51.896",
   "2013-08-23T12:10:51.896",
   "2013-08-26T10:30:13.601",
   "2013-08-26T10:30:13.617",
   "2013-08-26T10:30:13.617",
   "2013-08-26T10:31:20.573",
   "2013-08-26T10:31:20.573",
   "2013-08-26T10:31:20.573",
   "2013-08-27T11:59:56.73",
   "2013-08-27T11:59:56.777",
   "2013-08-27T11:59:56.777",
   "2013-08-27T19:43:06.866",
   "2013-08-27T19:43:06.928",
   "2013-08-27T19:43:06.928"
]
```

**EXPECTED RESULTS:**

```
[
   "2013-08-23T12:10:25.407",
   "2013-08-23T12:10:51.896",
   "2013-08-26T10:30:13.601",
   "2013-08-26T10:31:20.573",
   "2013-08-27T11:59:56.73",
   "2013-08-27T19:43:06.866",
]
```

Is there a query I can use to only get the parent objects' LastUpdated fields?

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured it out:

```
$[*].LastUpdated -> only the parents
$[*].Product.LastUpdated -> only the product
$[*].Reviewer.LastUpdated -> only the reviewer
```

Comment: How did you manage to get this working? All I get with this is "We can not find any data with path [". Only thing that works is $..fieldName, but that gets me the same trouble as you - it fetches data from nested elements.

Comment: @lukfi: Honestly, I don't remember. I spent a few months last year rewriting my entire ETL in Python3 and ditching Kettle completely. Sorry I can't be more help. What definitely helped me figure it out at the time was finding a decent JSONPath tester online.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Chris. I didn't know that JsonPath testers exist. Now I see that your answer is correct, but Kettle 5.1 is broken. Do you, by any chance, remember which version of Kettle did you use?

Comment: ...nevermind. **Abandon all hope, ye who enter here!** It's been broken for years and Pentaho refuses to fix it. http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-5143